# Why I cannot get the string without tokens with the program I have written?

Tags: java, string

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String s = scan.nextLine();
 Queue q=new LinkedList();
 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
     int x=(int)s.charAt(i);
     if(x<65 || (x>90 && x<97) || x>122) {
         q.add(s.charAt(i));
     }
 }
 System.out.println(q.peek());
 String redex="";
 while(!q.isEmpty()) {
     redex+=q.remove();
 }
 String[] x=s.split(redex,-1);
 for(String y:x) {
     if(y!=null)
         System.out.println(y);
 }

 scan.close();
```

I am trying to print the string "my name is NLP and I, so, works:fine;"yes"." without tokens such as **{[]}+-_)*&%$** but it just prints out all the String as it is, and I don't understand the problem?

Comment: In addition to what @ThibautB.said split takes a regex, with your string, it just looks for all the characters and says i am unable to split by those special characters.

Comment: All those characters match your condition, int values : `123,91,93,125,43,45,95,41,42,38,37,36` .

Comment: By the way, a word of caution: your `while` loop may become very inefficient if the string gets large, because the `String` class is immutable, and every time you do `redex+=q.remove()` you are creating a new string as a copy of the old one plus the new character, with the number of copied characters getting larger and larger each time. It's better to use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

This is 3 answers in one:

- For your initial problem
- For a solution without regex
- For a correct use of Scanner (this is up to you).

**First**

When you use a regex build from whatever character you got under the hand, you should quote it:

```
String[] x=s.split(Pattern.quote(redex),-1);
```

That would be the usual problem, but the second problem is that you are building a regexp range but you are omitting the `[]` making the range, so it can work as is:

```
String[] x=s.split("[" + Pattern.quote(redex) + "]",-1);
```

This one *may* work, but may fail if `Pattern.quote` don't quote `-` and `-` is found in between two characters making a range such as : `$-!`.

This would means: character in range starting at `$` from `!`. It may fail if the range is invalid and my example may be invalid (`$` may be after `!`).

Finally, you may use:

```
String redex = q.stream()
                .map(Pattern::quote)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

This regexp should match the unwanted character.

**Second:**

For the rest, the other answer point out another problem: you are not using the `Character.isXXX` method to check for valid characters.

Firstly, be wary that some method does not use `char` but code points. For example, [isAlphabetic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) use code points. A code points is simply a representation of a character in a multibyte encoding. There some unicode character which take two `char`.

Secondly, I think your problem lies in the fact you are not using the right tool to split your words.

In pseudo code, this should be:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = line.length(); i < n; ++i) {
  // if the character fail to match, then we switched from word to non word
  if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(line.charAt(i)) {
    if (offset != i) {
      words.add(line.substring(offset, i));
    }
    offset = i + 1; // next char
  }
}
if (offset != line.length()) {
  words.add(line.substring(offset));
}
```

This would:
- Find transition from word to non word and change offset (where we started)
- Add word to the list
- Add the last token as ending word.

**Last**

Alternatively, you may also play with `Scanner` class since it allows you to input a custom delimiter for its `hasNext()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

I quote the class javadoc:

> The scanner can also use delimiters other than whitespace. This
>   example reads several items in from a string:
>
> ```
>      String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
>      Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
>      System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>      System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>      System.out.println(s.next());
>      System.out.println(s.next());
>      s.close();
> ```

As you guessed, you may pass on any delimiter and then use `hasNext()` and `next()` to get only valid words.

For example, using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` would split on each non alpha/digit transition.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, the condition `x<65` will catch all sorts of special characters you're not interested in. Using [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)'s built-in methods will help you write this condition in a clearer, bug-free way:

```
x = s.charAt(i);
if (Character.isLetter(x) || Character.isWhiteSpace(x)) {
    q.add(x);
}
```